# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de pasar parametros en un modelo mvc?

Tags: javascript, mvc, poo, parametros

Suponiendo que quiero crear un usuario y obtengo la información desde la interfaz grafica (vista) y quiero que esa información pase por el controlador que a su vez la enviará al modelo, cual es la mejor forma de enviar los parametros a través de estos elementos:

```
//Vista
controlador.crearUsuario(dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4)

//Controlador
crearUsuario(dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4){
    modelo.crearUsuario(dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4)
}

//Modelo
crearUsuario(dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4){
    this.usuario = new Usuario(dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4)
}
```

o Por si el contrario lo mejor sería

```
//Vista
objeto = new Usuario(dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4)
controlador.crearUsuario(objeto)

//Controlador
crearUsuario(objeto){
    modelo.crearUsuario(objeto)
}

//Modelo
crearUsuario(objeto){
    this.usuario = objeto
}
```

¿cual es la mejor forma de pasar parametros teniendo en cuenta las buenas practicas del modelo mvc y la teoría de encapsulamiento del paradigma de POO? (preferiblemente en lenguajes como Javascript)

Comment: Hasta donde yo  tenía  entendido. Es una mala práctica realizar lógica en un modelo.  Los modelos  deberían ser  solo una clase con sus propiedades,sin lógica???

Answer (score 0):

La segunda opción.

Si el día de mañana hay que añadir un *dato5* solo vas a tener que agregarlo en la vista y modificarlo en el modelo conforme a lo que requiera la aplicación. De lo contrario, cada vez que tengas que agregar un nuevo *dato* tendrías que modificar todos los archivos para adaptarlo.

También depende mucho de la aplicación. Pero de todas formas, la segunda sería la más mantenible.